# MFC CGridListCtrlEx

Tags: mfc

In MFC CGridListCtrlEx how can I insert image to the right of the cell. I can add image to the right but that works only for the column heading by using flag LVCFMT_BITMAP_ON_RIGHT. All I want to do is to add image to the right of cell, by default the images are getting added towards the left.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please spend some time and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/) to get accustomed to site. Also check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I believe only LVCOLUMN not LVITEM allows for alignment. Which you have discovered. I think your only recourse may be Owner Draw for each cell which might also give you more layout flexibility.